# Apply an elevator pitch and CTA above the fold on a webpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, design, sales

Not to sure if I'm in the write place but I'm a web designer trying to expand my skills into marketing and copyrighting.

It can take anywhere between 3 to 8 seconds for someone to decide if your webpage is worth reading before going somewhere else. I want to help my clients be able to convert users into customers but with potentially only 8 seconds to wow someone this can be very hard.

I understand without knowing your target audience and the true benefits your products or services can offer them then your kind of pissing in the wind if you believe you can convert people.

So my question is; Can anyone offer some advice or known resources where I can begin to understand and control the power of combining elevator pitches, calls to action, etc. alongside images and other visual graphics all above the fold.

Basically some tips and tricks on how to use these tools to help convert people into customers.

Thank you for your time and hopefully all makes sense

Comment: This is not really the forum for this sort of enquiry as the Salesforce.stackexchange.com site is for questions relating to the Salesforce CRM system.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are many sites that are suitable in the Stackexchange network for this, but possibly https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ or some of the others might have helpful content or be in scope for this.

Comment: Thank you! I was a little unsure by the name but looking at other questions around here I can see what you mean, thank you for your time

Comment: Maybe: http://ux.stackexchange.com ?? maybe